# executing PHP header location only if is browser

Tags: php

I have a problem in my site with "visits" of  external pages.
The problem is in creation of cookies, my script try to create cookies on first visit. When the page is read from external page (like W3C) i am getting Redirect loop.
So how i can only execute `header("location:*");` in browsers.

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

Don't do specific cases. Treat everyone the same. You'll have a hard time doing the "detection".

Add a GET parameter on the redirection. And don't redirect anymore when the param exists.

Answer (score 1):

Not all browsers will accept cookies. Not all things that are not browsers will reject cookies. Trying to use the type of user agent to guess if it will accept your cookies is doomed to failure.

Change your workflow instead:

1. Redirect to the set-a-cookie page
2. Set a cookie
3. Redirect to a different is-there-a-cookie page
4. Display error message or redirect to the page they came in on

Better yet, don't require cookies until cookies are actually required (which is probably "When the user logs in" rather then "When you want to start gathering analytics data"). Note that the preceding sentence includes some largish assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

By using "User-agent" string, you can easily block your code from executing under conditional statements.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";
```